# Transparent, floating Android Activity doesn't allow updates to content behind it

Tags: android, android-activity, overlay, transparent, floating

I have tried and tried to get a transparent, floating Activity to show up (as an overlay), but allow whatever is behind it to still show AND update. Right now it seems that if the Activity behind mine is closed or a new one opens (could be either in this case), the new underneath Activity does not shine through my Activity to the user.

I have tried every combination of Flags I can come up with, and at this point I'm assuming Flags are not the answer. Can anyone help me find the proper code to do such a thing?

Before anyone asks, I have a valid use case for this type of Activity; no, I don't plan to annoy the user with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. It should be possible to create an activity using the theme Theme.Dialog or Theme.Translucent (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to have whatever activity is beneath it still show at least partially. The problem is, is that the Activity below will be Paused (it's onPause will have fired, but it's onStop will not have) and I don't believe it is possible in any way to have it run any code.

Comment: Yes, true... if a Broadcast Receiver is registered in an Activity, it would fire.

Answer (score 1):

I have not investigated in making a transparent `Activity` but I don't think it's possible in an `Activity` way. This seems to be logical since even if you have a transparent `Activity` it's still relying on the `View` inside it - the `View` makes the transparent part, not the `Activity`. This means you're probably gonna end up with a transparent `View` instead.

If you have a "front" `Activity` with a transparent `View` and then a "back" `Activity`, the "back" `Activity` would not be visible to the user - and that's because you're in another `Activity`.

So, the correct way is to use a transparent `View`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to update the activity below by implementing a Broadcast receiver on it, and sending Broadcasts from whenever you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only do this if I own the below activity. I need to show over any activity, including those of any other app. Your point is valid within the same app though :)